# Why WPF cut components when I run the program

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a WPF program, with some textbox, labels and buttons. 
Using the XAML designer, it works fine, the components are shown as they should. But when I run the program, it seems that the window shortens and cut some components in the sides.

Why are the components (button and labbel) being cut only when I run the program?

Here's the Xaml code of the 2 affected components:

```
<Window x:Class="XML_Edit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XML_Edit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="XML_Edit" Height="380" Width="470" ResizeMode="NoResize" Icon="Imagenes/xml.png">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FF363944">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="49*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="183*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Components -->
    <Button Name="btCambiarContenido" Grid.Row="4" Content="Cambiar Contenido" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="26,80,0,16" Height="36" Width="135" Click="BtCambiarContenido_Click" TabIndex="5" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF4EB8CE" FontSize="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="#FF4EB8CE"/>

    <Label Name="lbSeleccionarRuta" Grid.Row="1" ToolTip="Seleccionar archivo" Height="32" Width="32" Margin="293.333,32,41,16" MouseDown="LbSeleccionarRuta_MouseDown" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes/folder_azul.png"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes/folder_gris.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

They are shown fine in the WPF editor:
[image: WPF Editor]

But they fet cut when I run the program:
[image]

Comment: Because you can never trust the XAML designer, With those Margins I guess you just used Drag&Drop and moved around with the items. It might look good in the designer, but when running the program you cannot trust it. That was the simple answer, and for why it is cutting: Because your grid  width and height with the combination of Window width and height is less than the space needed for the items.

Comment: You have incorrect `Grid` layout, have a look at articles, how to properly do that (like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-a-grid-for-automatic-layout))

Comment: Vote to keep open. It's a perfectly valid question with a close-to-mcve and a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting your Button height to 36 pixels and giving it a margin of 26,80,0,16. This is effectively telling the layout manager that you want 36+80+16=132 pixels reserved to accommodate that button in row 4.

Meanwhile, in your grid layout you're specifying the rows 0-3 to have 15+80+80+45 pixels reserved. Combined with the 132 you're reserving for your button that's 352. But you're also explicitly setting your window height to 380, and that has to accommodate not just your 352 client area pixels but also the border and caption (as an experiment set your `WindowStyle` to `None` to remove the border and caption bar and you'll see your full control appear again). The layout manager has to cut pixels somewhere, and since row 4 is the only one you've specified with a "*" that's where they get cut, so the top and bottom of your button get cut as well. The reason you're not seeing this in designer is because it's using different theming to your OS, which is taking into account things like screen DPI, Windows theme settings, accessibility and several other things; the caption bar in designer is simply a bit smaller.

Issues like this are one of the many reasons you have to be careful doing explicit pixel layouts in WPF, and why you have to be especially careful with margins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll have a look at that.